# Is the completion of Puiseux series spherical complete?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $S$ be a completion of the field of formal Puiseux series over $\mathbb C$. Is $S$ spherical complete? It should be not spherical complete. I tried some examples, but failed to find an right example. Any suggestions? Thanks,

Comment: definition of "completion"?

Comment: See Example 1.5.8 of Kedlaya's [p-adic Differential Equations](http://www.cambridge.org/us/academic/subjects/mathematics/number-theory/p-adic-differential-equations).